# Do Dart Isolates in Flutter have a native implementation aka map to threads?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

The title pretty much says it all: Do Dart Isolates in Flutter have a native implementation aka map to threads? Because especially on iOS I would assume that it has to go through some objective C or Swift layer to access the CPU.

I was unable to find an answer on Google or on the Flutter page.

Answer (score 0):

In general Threads are light weight processes they bring concurrency/multi-tasking into system,

*Each Dart isolate has a single thread of execution and shares no mutable objects with other isolates*

I hope this makes you clear about dart Isolates.

Comment: Not really. I am more concerned with the native implementation on android and iOS or rather whether there is even one. 

To put it differently ist there anything in between dart isolates and their access to the CPU on mobile devices. Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Obviously on low level every process/thread needs CPU.

Comment: hi  check this you will get some idea how dart/flutter internally interacts on low level with Android and IOS 
https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview

Comment: In recent Flutter versions, isolates are no longer backed by OS threads. Instead, a native thread pool is responsible for running Dart isolates: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/36097

Answer (score 0):

No, dart has no native implementation for mapping to threads.

I also writing on Delphi and C#, dart isolates is a quite difficult to understand when you are used to creating threads with a single line of code in other platforms.

I recommend look on plugins, such as [easy_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_isolate) or [dart_thread](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_thread) if you often using threads in flutter app